# Sql vs flatfiles and some secutity related issues

Tags: asp.net, mysql, security

The basic requirement of the site is to provide a plateform for blogging and  single interface for managing various social network, emails, blog etc.
For blogging I am using .netblogengine. And facebook and gmail and blogger are currently being managed by signing in via their api.
I am using mysql and blog content is being saved in mysql column.

My first question is.. Suppose instead of saving blog content in mysql table column I just save the content in a txt file and save the name of the file in the column.. Doing so will reduce the size of table but will it also affect the performance?? I know I will not be able to search within the content but mysql size grows up quickly (50 mb with 8 users). The minimum number of users are atleast 30.

My second question.. I am thinking of asking all the acount (facebook, gmail etc) username and password and store them in the db. When even a user sign in all related account will be signed in using the saved data so that separate logging is not required. How ever username/password hacks are common headlines now days. I want to know how secure are the shared server environment in this regard? Will I be required to take some extra effort to secure these data or I can be sure that as long as my mysql logging details are safe all data are safe.

Comment: What "shared server environment" are you speaking of specifically?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is saving text content like blog post in the database is going to be the best bet. Saving any attachments if there are any in separate files is a good idea though.

The data size on your disk is going to be similar either way, so there's no savings there. And since you would need to develop a unique naming convention for the text files you'd essentially be programming a partial database yourself; might as well leave it to the experts :)

In general, the table size getting to hundreds of megabytes is not going to hurt performance substantially. Assuming you've set up your indexes appropriately, the database engine will be able to seek directly to the data it needs.

Short answer on the account credentials, definitely don't save either username or especially password in unencrypted form in the database. It would be a question for the security experts on how to properly encrypt these to ensure security. https://security.stackexchange.com/